# jquery plugin add event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery plugin that I have created, that shows content and hides content in a tab like interface. What I am wanting to is trigger an event when some content is shown that I can then listen for in my source code, and fire an event based on that is that possible?

Here is my plugin,

```js
$.fn.appsTabs = function(options){

  // These are the defaults.
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults.
    selected: "home"
  }, options );

  // Set Active
  $(this).find('.pops-tabs-navigation li[data-route="'+settings.selected+'"]').addClass('active');

  // Hide All Boxes and show first one
  $(this).find('.apps-tabs-content .pops-tab-content').addClass('cloak');
  $(this).find('.pops-tabs-content .pops-tab-content#content-'+settings.selected).removeClass('cloak');
  // Get Clicks on Li in Navigation
  $(this).find('.apps-tabs-navigation li').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
      // Get ID of Tab
      id = $(this).attr('id');
      tabid = 'content-'+id;

      // Set Active
      $(this).parent('.apps-tabs-navigation').find('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      // Hide all boxes
      $(this).parent('.apps-tabs-navigation').parents('.pops-tabs').find('.pops-tabs-content .pops-tab-content').addClass('cloak');
      $(this).parent('.apps-tabs-navigation').parents('.pops-tabs').find('.pops-tabs-content #'+tabid).removeClass('cloak');
    }
  });
}
```

Is it possible to maybe add something to the prototype and listen for that in my main application code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plugin code, you can trigger a custom event and listen to it in the page javascript:

**Plugin**

```
// Show your element (example)
$('#myElement').show();
// Trigger custom event
$(document).trigger('myCustomPluginEvent');
```

**Page**

```
// Event listener for custom event 'myCustomPluginEvent'
$(document).on('myCustomPluginEvent', function() {
   // Do something when custom event occurs
});
```